# Why doesn't Stack Overflow use thematic sections?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm doing some background research on the utility (or lack thereof) of stactic "sections" in Q&A sites, and more specifically, on Stack Overflow.

What I mean by that are sections like a "Python section", or a "MySQL section", where you need to put all your MySQL questions. Is there any information about testing or data that Stack Exchange used to decide that they shouldn't use this type of taxonomy?

Comment: Heya Massimo -- we figured out what you were asking! Thanks for editing and making your post clearer! :)

Comment: This makes more sense! But these sections exist in the form of tags, don't they?

Comment: @Pekka Yup! I believe the OP is asking why we use tags and not subforums, like traditional sites do.

Comment: Are you talking about something like [facebook.SO](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com)? It just doesn't work.

Comment: @six but is that the concept's fault? Hardly. See the discussion below.

Comment: @Pekka: at this point the concept is less useful than simply {tagname}.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand what you're getting at, you mean something like a sub-forum. [They did a private beta](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html) as well as internal tests before the site launched for UI issues, and presumably tagging vs. sub-fora came up then, or during design. Of course, 4 years of activity is its own test, demonstrating on the concept works reasonably well.

However, I don't recall anything other than that initial user testing, like in the form of studies or anything like that. [Joel Spolsky put it best as to why they used it](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html) in his launch blog post:

> We have tags. Every question is tagged so, for example, if you’re a Ruby guru, you can ignore everything but Ruby and just treat Stack Overflow as a great Ruby Q&A site. A single question can have multiple tags, so you don’t have to figure out which single category it fits

That aside, Stack Exchange *does* have a *form* of static categorization with tags. For example, if you go to [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), you'll get:

- All the questions about MySQL
- A [helpful starter guide](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info)
- A list of [the top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/topusers)
- A link to a [job search](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/mysql).

And of course, there's the [Facebook Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/) example, which is even closer to the idea of "static thematic sections", but turned out to be [somewhat of a failure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership). The difference is that the categorization isn't determined from the top-down, but by the users themselves in, [as Jeff Atwood put it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/), a "[folksonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy)".

Comment: *"Facebook Stack Overflow."* Currently a source of many off-topic FB support questions.

Comment: @Null but that's arguably not as much the concept's fault than it is the audience's.

Comment: @pek - not all blame can be placed on the users. Facebook's (lack of) support is also at play. At one stage Facebook was even [misleading people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126114/stack-overflow-and-facebook-policy-matters-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

A big thing about Stack Overflow is that it's Language Agnostic and, due to the tag system, there's no limit to the amount of topics.

The "sub-forum" concept breaks apart quickly as you add more sub-fora than you can count on one hand (let alone two), and also creates massive divides that tags don't, which harms the "language agnostic" sense of it all.

Tags just make a lot more sense here, and "sections" just plain wouldn't work; SO would have as many sections (or more) than the Stack Exchange Network has *sites* (and SE has a *lot* of sites).

Tags are also easily editable in a way that "topic" isn't. You can be in multiple tags and change tags easily, being in multiple topics and changing topics (and this locations of the question) gets...weird, really fast.

Comment: +1 I abhor the concept of classifying items with a single category (folders, subforums, etc.). It's one of the reasons why I switched from Yahoo Mail to Gmail many moons ago. The 1GB vs 6MB at the time helped too.