# Where is the good place to ask Facebook policy related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, facebook

While I was searching for Facebook's developer policy questions on Stack Exchange, I found *[Platform policy for Facebook, developers & page managers [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757260/platform-policy-q-for-facebook-developers-page-managers)* .

After seeing that, I'm asking myself: Where would be the good place to ask a question about the [Facebook Developer Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126114/stack-overflow-and-facebook-policy-matters-on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you would ask on a place other than Facebook. Our communities aren't affiliated with Facebook as much as they want us to think, so we aren't in as much of a position to answer policy questions as Facebook themselves are.

Comment: It's more about interpretation and it's pretty much impossible to get an answer from them. It's questions about what I can do or not, that are unclear in some points. Should I still refer to them for interpretation? How can I get an answer then?

Comment: @Jean-François, I understand that it's hard to get an answer from Facebook itself. Honestly, I don't think we have an answer for you. Note that Facebook no longer (mistakenly) refers people to Stack Overflow for answers to policy questions, as they did in the link from the question you reference.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisG.B. The problem is, we don't want to act as a proxy for customer support questions for *any* company, including Facebook.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you!